# Activity base class?

Tags: android

What is Activity base class: java.lang.Object or android.content.Context?

The class overview is not clear to me (see the image please).

[image]

Comment: "extends X" tells you what the direct base class is. Is this all you're asking? In this case, the direct base class `ContextThemeWrapper` is a class "that allows you to modify the theme from what is in the wrapped context".

Comment: That is also true. Is this class called via super.() in the Android Activity class?

Comment: That's a very basic Android question. I can recommend the [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) if you are starting out with Android programming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Java every class has an `Object` as a superclass (You can also have more information [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)). `Context` is a Java class hence it has  `Object` at the root of its inheritance tree hierarchy. `Context` is a class that holds information about an application environment as described in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), and `Activity` has it in its inheritance tree.

Comment: You are logical. I thought the same until I read that Context is the base class of Activity class in Android. That's why I asked this.

Comment: To clarify on what Amokrane said: that means that all classes in class overview which are above android.app.Activity are its base classes :)

Comment: When I call super in Android Activity, does it refer to Object or Context class???

Comment: When you are in your activity it refers to the `Activity` class (since you are extending `Activity`). Inside the class `Activity` itself calling `super` would refer to `ContextThemeWrapper`, its direct superclass. You need to read the inheritance tree from the bottom not from the top.

Comment: Thanks, now it's all clear to me. Sorry for bothering you with this.

Answer (score 3):

Context is the base class for Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Activity Tree Hierarchy

```
My Activity

↓extends

AppCompatActivity

↓extends

FragmentActivity

↓extends

ComponentActivity

↓extends

androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity

↓extends

Activity

↓extends

ContextThemeWrapper

↓extends

ContextWrapper

↓extends

Context
(This is base abstract Base Class)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was confuse the about the base class of an android, Is Object is the base class or Activity is the base class??? but i studied and found the solution.

The **Application** class in **Android is the base class** within an Android app that contains all other components such as activities and services. The Application class, or any subclass of the Application class, is instantiated before any other class when the process for your application/package is created.